# First steps in creating a plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I have a good understanding of css/html, but I'm on my beginning stages of php. I have already read the rules of creating a plugin for wordpress.

And i have actually created a small plugin that adds a div box at the top of all admin pages that display´s my information and adds a button that emails me if they need to contact me.

My next step of the process is to make an admin menu settings for the plugin. And inside the settings page I would like to have fields, checkboxes that do stuff.

For example:

1. checkbox that removes the button
2. textbox where you can add new functions to the bottom of the php file of the plugin.

How canI do that? But I like to get an understanding of how to make the settings page interact with the plugin.php file. Comment out lines of the code, add new lines, activate features, etc.

Here is my plugin code:

```
    <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: XXXXXXXXX
    Plugin URI:  http://www.XXXXXXXXX.is
    Description: Þetta plugin setur inn hjálpar glugga í admin menu. Með síma, upplýsingum og takka til að senda Tactica póst.
    Version:     1.0
    Author:      Aron Hallsson
    Author URI:  http://XXXXXXXXX.is/
    License:     GPL2
    License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
    Domain Path: /languages
    Text Domain: XXXXXXXXX
    */

    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies!' );

    // Hjálpin hérna
    // =========================================
    function my_admin_notice() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap wrapDivide">
            <p><?php _e( '<div class="aron1 aron2"><img src="http://XXXXXXXXX.is/logo.png" class="mynd"><a href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><button class="arontakki">Smelltu hér til að senda mér póst !</button></a><h3 class="adstod">Vantar þig aðstoð með vefinn ??<br />Ekkert mál , ég er í síma XXXXXXXXX</h3></div>', 'aron-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );

    // Bæti við stylesheet css á takkana
    // ==================================
    function custom_admin_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-css', plugins_url('/style.css', __FILE__), array(), null, 'all' );
        }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_scripts' );

// Extra codes here below    
//========================
```

---

Here is the CSS if anyone is interested in adding this plugin to their page.
It has a nice CSS animation to it :-)

```
/*!
 * COMPANY NAME (http://YOURDOMAIN.com/)
 * Author : YOURNAME YOURPHONENUMBER
 * 
 */

.aron2{
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);                                      
     box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
     width: 98%;
     border: 1px solid;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 15px;
     text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     animation: animate-bg 2s linear infinite;
     border-radius: 5px;
     height: 75px;
     clear: both;
}

.aron1{
     background-color: #4ea5cd;
     border-color: #3b8eb5;
}

@keyframes animate-bg {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
       background-position: -80px 0;
    }
}

.mynd {

box-shadow: 3px 3px 60px white; 
float: left;
padding: 16px; 
background-color: whitesmoke; 
border-radius: 5px; 
margin-right: 20px;
}

.arontakki {
float: right; 
margin-right: 15px; 
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.29); 
padding: 20px; 
color: white; 
margin-top: 10px;  
border: 1px solid blue; 
border-radius: 5px; 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px black;
}

button.arontakki:hover {
    background-color: #00A0D2;
    border: 1px solid #00A0D2; 
    cursor: auto;
}

.adstod {
color: white;
}

/*
* removing the comments will hide the plugin from plugin page :-)
tr#tactica-admin-hjalpin {
    display: none;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress plugins works by `actions` and `filters`. if you developed a plugin you will know what an action and filter are. to if you want possiblity to update the code based on settings there should be an [add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) or [apply_filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) based on your need. it will be better than updating entire code if used effectively. if you want an examples you can take a look at [woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce) plugin, which uses these for usage by itself and for other plugins

Comment: thanks for the response.
So basically , i need to add actions and filters to my plugin ,
And then somehow hook the checkbox up to those actions and filters ?

Comment: yes. it is more flexible way to do this. you can use even use them like `$checks = apply_filters( 'myplugin_checks', $this->checks );`

Comment: Thanks for the help , will mark this as the answer ..I will try to learn from your examples. ..  If you have time , i´d be very happy if you could give me an example of how I´d make a checkbox disable a function in **my php file**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Demo Plugin
Description: example plugin to demonstrate wordpress capatabilities
Plugin URI: http://test/
Author URI: http://test/
Author: Test
License: Public Domain
Version: 1.1
*/
/* here all code for active / deactive / delete plugin with listing data.
 note : you just follew part 1,2,3,4 and your plugin Ready For Implement.
*/
/**
    * PART 1. Defining Custom Database Table
    * ============================================================================
    *
    * In this part you are going to define custom database table,
    * create it, update, and fill with some dummy data
    *
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins
    *
    * In case your are developing and want to check plugin use:
    *
    * DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_custome_plugin;
    * DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'custom_table_demo_install_data';
    *
    * to drop table and option
    */

/**
    * $custom_table_demo_db_version - holds current database version
    * and used on plugin update to sync database tables
    */
global $custom_table_demo_db_version;
$custom_table_demo_db_version = '1.1'; // version changed from 1.0 to 1.1

/**
    * register_activation_hook implementation
    *
    * will be called when user activates plugin first time
    * must create needed database tables
    */
function custom_table_demo_install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $custom_table_demo_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custome_plugin'; // do not forget about tables prefix

    // sql to create your table
    // NOTICE that:
    // 1. each field MUST be in separate line
    // 2. There must be two spaces between PRIMARY KEY and its name
    //    Like this: PRIMARY KEY[space][space](id)
    // otherwise dbDelta will not work
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        age int(11) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

    // we do not execute sql directly
    // we are calling dbDelta which cant migrate database
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    // save current database version for later use (on upgrade)
    add_option('custom_table_demo_db_version', $custom_table_demo_db_version);

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] Example of updating to 1.1 version
        *
        * If you develop new version of plugin
        * just increment $custom_table_demo_db_version variable
        * and add following block of code
        *
        * must be repeated for each new version
        * in version 1.1 we change email field
        * to contain 200 chars rather 100 in version 1.0
        * and again we are not executing sql
        * we are using dbDelta to migrate table changes
        */
    $installed_ver = get_option('custom_table_demo_db_version');
    if ($installed_ver != $custom_table_demo_db_version) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name tinytext NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            age int(11) NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

        // notice that we are updating option, rather than adding it
        update_option('custom_table_demo_db_version', $custom_table_demo_db_version);
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'custom_table_demo_install');

/**
    * register_activation_hook implementation
    *
    * [OPTIONAL]
    * additional implementation of register_activation_hook
    * to insert some dummy data
    */
function custom_table_demo_install_data()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custome_plugin'; // do not forget about tables prefix

    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
        'name' => 'Jhon',
        'email' => 'jhon@test.com',
        'age' => 29
    ));
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
        'name' => 'Babita',
        'email' => 'babita@test.com',
        'age' => 26
    ));
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'custom_table_demo_install_data');

/**
    * Trick to update plugin database, see docs
    */
function custom_table_demo_update_db_check()
{
    global $custom_table_demo_db_version;
    if (get_site_option('custom_table_demo_db_version') != $custom_table_demo_db_version) {
        custom_table_demo_install();
    }
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'custom_table_demo_update_db_check');

/**
    * PART 2. Defining Custom Table List
    * ============================================================================
    *
    * In this part you are going to define custom table list class,
    * that will display your database records in nice looking table
    *
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table
    * http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/
    */

if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php');
}

/**
    * custom_table_demo_List_Table class that will display our custom table
    * records in nice table
    */
class custom_table_demo_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
    /**
        * [REQUIRED] You must declare constructor and give some basic params
        */
    function __construct()
    {
        global $status, $page;

        parent::__construct(array(
            'singular' => 'demo',
            'plural' => 'demos',
        ));
    }

    /**
        * [REQUIRED] this is a default column renderer
        *
        * @param $item - row (key, value array)
        * @param $column_name - string (key)
        * @return HTML
        */
    function column_default($item, $column_name)
    {
        return $item[$column_name];
    }

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] this is example, how to render specific column
        *
        * method name must be like this: "column_[column_name]"
        *
        * @param $item - row (key, value array)
        * @return HTML
        */
    function column_age($item)
    {
        return '<em>' . $item['age'] . '</em>';
    }

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] this is example, how to render column with actions,
        * when you hover row "Edit | Delete" links showed
        *
        * @param $item - row (key, value array)
        * @return HTML
        */
    function column_name($item)
    {
        // links going to /admin.php?page=[your_plugin_page][&other_params]
        // notice how we used $_REQUEST['page'], so action will be done on curren page
        // also notice how we use $this->_args['singular'] so in this example it will
        // be something like &demo=2
        $actions = array(
            'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=demos_form&id=%s">%s</a>', $item['id'], __('Edit', 'custom_table_demo')),
            'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Delete', 'custom_table_demo')),
        );

        return sprintf('%s %s',
            $item['name'],
            $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }

    /**
        * [REQUIRED] this is how checkbox column renders
        *
        * @param $item - row (key, value array)
        * @return HTML
        */
    function column_cb($item)
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />',
            $item['id']
        );
    }

    /**
        * [REQUIRED] This method return columns to display in table
        * you can skip columns that you do not want to show
        * like content, or description
        *
        * @return array
        */
    function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
            'name' => __('Name', 'custom_table_demo'),
            'email' => __('E-Mail', 'custom_table_demo'),
            'age' => __('Age', 'custom_table_demo'),
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] This method return columns that may be used to sort table
        * all strings in array - is column names
        * notice that true on name column means that its default sort
        *
        * @return array
        */
    function get_sortable_columns()
    {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'name' => array('name', true),
            'email' => array('email', false),
            'age' => array('age', false),
        );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] Return array of bult actions if has any
        *
        * @return array
        */
    function get_bulk_actions()
    {
        $actions = array(
            'delete' => 'Delete'
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    /**
        * [OPTIONAL] This method processes bulk actions
        * it can be outside of class
        * it can not use wp_redirect coz there is output already
        * in this example we are processing delete action
        * message about successful deletion will be shown on page in next part
        */
    function process_bulk_action()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custome_plugin'; // do not forget about tables prefix

        if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
            $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
            if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

            if (!empty($ids)) {
                $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN($ids)");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
        * [REQUIRED] This is the most important method
        *
        * It will get rows from database and prepare them to be showed in table
        */
    function prepare_items()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custome_plugin'; // do not forget about tables prefix

        $per_page = 5; // constant, how much records will be shown per page

        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

        // here we configure table headers, defined in our methods
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

        // [OPTIONAL] process bulk action if any
        $this->process_bulk_action();

        // will be used in pagination settings
        $total_items = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table_name");

        // prepare query params, as usual current page, order by and order direction
        $paged = isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? ($per_page * max(0, intval($_REQUEST['paged']) - 1)) : 0;
        $orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'name';
        $order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc';

        // [REQUIRED] define $items array
        // notice that last argument is ARRAY_A, so we will retrieve array
        $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $per_page, $paged), ARRAY_A);

        // [REQUIRED] configure pagination
        $this->set_pagination_args(array(
            'total_items' => $total_items, // total items defined above
            'per_page' => $per_page, // per page constant defined at top of method
            'total_pages' => ceil($total_items / $per_page) // calculate pages count
        ));
    }
}

/**
    * PART 3. Admin page
    * ============================================================================
    *
    * In this part you are going to add admin page for custom table
    *
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus
    */

/**
    * admin_menu hook implementation, will add pages to list demos and to add new one
    */
function custom_table_demo_admin_menu()
{
    add_menu_page(__('demos', 'custom_table_demo'), __('demos', 'custom_table_demo'), 'activate_plugins', 'demos', 'custom_table_demo_demos_page_handler');
    add_submenu_page('demos', __('demos', 'custom_table_demo'), __('demos', 'custom_table_demo'), 'activate_plugins', 'demos', 'custom_table_demo_demos_page_handler');
    // add new will be described in next part
    add_submenu_page('demos', __('Add new', 'custom_table_demo'), __('Add new', 'custom_table_demo'), 'activate_plugins', 'demos_form', 'custom_table_demo_demos_form_page_handler');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_table_demo_admin_menu');

/**
    * List page handler
    *
    * This function renders our custom table
    * Notice how we display message about successfull deletion
    * Actualy this is very easy, and you can add as many features
    * as you want.
    *
    * Look into /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-*-list-table.php for examples
    */
function custom_table_demo_demos_page_handler()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table = new custom_table_demo_List_Table();
    $table->prepare_items();

    $message = '';
    if ('delete' === $table->current_action()) {
        $message = '<div class="updated below-h2" id="message"><p>' . sprintf(__('Items deleted: %d', 'custom_table_demo'), count($_REQUEST['id'])) . '</p></div>';
    }
    ?>
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="icon32 icon32-posts-post" id="icon-edit"><br></div>
    <h2><?php _e('demos', 'custom_table_demo')?> <a class="add-new-h2"
                                    href="<?php echo get_admin_url(get_current_blog_id(), 'admin.php?page=demos_form');?>"><?php _e('Add new', 'custom_table_demo')?></a>
    </h2>
    <?php echo $message; ?>

    <form id="demos-table" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>"/>
        <?php $table->display() ?>
    </form>

</div>
<?php
}

/**
    * PART 4. Form for adding andor editing row
    * ============================================================================
    *
    * In this part you are going to add admin page for adding andor editing items
    * You cant put all form into this function, but in this example form will
    * be placed into meta box, and if you want you can split your form into
    * as many meta boxes as you want
    *
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected
    */

/**
    * Form page handler checks is there some data posted and tries to save it
    * Also it renders basic wrapper in which we are callin meta box render
    */
function custom_table_demo_demos_form_page_handler()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custome_plugin'; // do not forget about tables prefix

    $message = '';
    $notice = '';

    // this is default $item which will be used for new records
    $default = array(
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'age' => null,
    );

    // here we are verifying does this request is post back and have correct nonce
    if (wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        // combine our default item with request params
        $item = shortcode_atts($default, $_REQUEST);
        // validate data, and if all ok save item to database
        // if id is zero insert otherwise update
        $item_valid = custom_table_demo_validate_demo($item);
        if ($item_valid === true) {
            if ($item['id'] == 0) {
                $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
                $item['id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
                if ($result) {
                    $message = __('Item was successfully saved', 'custom_table_demo');
                } else {
                    $notice = __('There was an error while saving item', 'custom_table_demo');
                }
            } else {
                $result = $wpdb->update($table_name, $item, array('id' => $item['id']));
                if ($result) {
                    $message = __('Item was successfully updated', 'custom_table_demo');
                } else {
                    $notice = __('There was an error while updating item', 'custom_table_demo');
                }
            }
        } else {
            // if $item_valid not true it contains error message(s)
            $notice = $item_valid;
        }
    }
    else {
        // if this is not post back we load item to edit or give new one to create
        $item = $default;
        if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
            $item = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d", $_REQUEST['id']), ARRAY_A);
            if (!$item) {
                $item = $default;
                $notice = __('Item not found', 'custom_table_demo');
            }
        }
    }

    // here we adding our custom meta box
    add_meta_box('demos_form_meta_box', 'demo data', 'custom_table_demo_demos_form_meta_box_handler', 'demo', 'normal', 'default');

    ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="icon32 icon32-posts-post" id="icon-edit"><br></div>
    <h2><?php _e('demo', 'custom_table_demo')?> <a class="add-new-h2"
                                href="<?php echo get_admin_url(get_current_blog_id(), 'admin.php?page=demos');?>"><?php _e('back to list', 'custom_table_demo')?></a>
    </h2>

    <?php if (!empty($notice)): ?>
    <div id="notice" class="error"><p><?php echo $notice ?></p></div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
    <div id="message" class="updated"><p><?php echo $message ?></p></div>
    <?php endif;?>

    <form id="form" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__))?>"/>
        <?php /* NOTICE: here we storing id to determine will be item added or updated */ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"/>

        <div class="metabox-holder" id="poststuff">
            <div id="post-body">
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <?php /* And here we call our custom meta box */ ?>
                    <?php do_meta_boxes('demo', 'normal', $item); ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'custom_table_demo')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}

/**
    * This function renders our custom meta box
    * $item is row
    *
    * @param $item
    */
function custom_table_demo_demos_form_meta_box_handler($item)
{
    ?>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" style="width: 100%;" class="form-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="name"><?php _e('Name', 'custom_table_demo')?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" style="width: 95%" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['name'])?>"
                    size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Your name', 'custom_table_demo')?>" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="email"><?php _e('E-Mail', 'custom_table_demo')?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" style="width: 95%" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['email'])?>"
                    size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Your E-Mail', 'custom_table_demo')?>" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="age"><?php _e('Age', 'custom_table_demo')?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="age" name="age" type="number" style="width: 95%" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['age'])?>"
                    size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Your age', 'custom_table_demo')?>" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}

/**
    * Simple function that validates data and retrieve bool on success
    * and error message(s) on error
    *
    * @param $item
    * @return bool|string
    */
function custom_table_demo_validate_demo($item)
{
    $messages = array();

    if (empty($item['name'])) $messages[] = __('Name is required', 'custom_table_demo');
    if (!empty($item['email']) && !is_email($item['email'])) $messages[] = __('E-Mail is in wrong format', 'custom_table_demo');
    if (!ctype_digit($item['age'])) $messages[] = __('Age in wrong format', 'custom_table_demo');
    //if(!empty($item['age']) && !absint(intval($item['age'])))  $messages[] = __('Age can not be less than zero');
    //if(!empty($item['age']) && !preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $item['age'])) $messages[] = __('Age must be number');
    //...

    if (empty($messages)) return true;
    return implode('<br />', $messages);
}

/**
    * Do not forget about translating your plugin, use __('english string', 'your_uniq_plugin_name') to retrieve translated string
    * and _e('english string', 'your_uniq_plugin_name') to echo it
    * in this example plugin your_uniq_plugin_name == custom_table_demo
    *
    * to create translation file, use poedit FileNew catalog...
    * Fill name of project, add "." to path (ENSURE that it was added - must be in list)
    * and on last tab add "__" and "_e"
    *
    * Name your file like this: [my_plugin]-[ru_RU].po
    *
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Internationalizing_Your_Plugin
    * http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers
    */
function custom_table_demo_languages()
{
    load_plugin_textdomain('custom_table_demo', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)));
}

add_action('init', 'custom_table_demo_languages');
```